# Get the vertices on a LineString either side of a point (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: c#, sql-server, geometry, .net, linear-referencing

I have a point that sits on top of a LineString, both Sql Geometry types.

```
POINT('0.5 0.5')

LINESTRING('0 0 NULL 1, 1 1 NULL 1')
```

I want to find the vertices of the LineString that lie either side of the point so that I can interpolate the Z and M values. Based on the values above my desired result would be:

```
POINT('0.5 0.5 NULL 0.5')
```

Can this be achieved in Sql Server 2008 or is there an add-on available to support this?

In reality I would be querying a LineString containing many points, not just two as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

See http://geographika.co.uk/linear-referencing-in-sql-server-2008, that offers sqlspatialtools ( http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/ ) But when i tested sqlspatialtools , i didn't get it work.

Far as i know ESRI C# libraries are easiest way to some processing in C#, FME also offers some interface for c#. I havent used those and both are commercial products

SQL server is good enough if you use it only for storing data, if you want have spatial tools in database and do some processing, use PostGIS. Easiest solution to your problem (for me)  is build C# program to read data from SQL server and then execute queries to PostGIS database if i really need to have that SQL server there. If SQL server is not needed then import data into PostGIS , do magic , export or i could use FME or QGIs to do job

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I grabbed the latest version of SqlSpatialTools. There were similar functions to what I need; however, these rely on STDistance() and not the 'M' value. I have added several functions to the library to do what I need but will need to test.